# Nestjs Request and Application Lifecycle

Tags: nestjs

I am looking for information about the request and application life-cycle for The NestJS framework. Specifically:

1. What is the order of execution of the following processes in a request, for a route that implements: `middleware`, `pipes`, `guards`, `interceptors`, and any other potential request process
2. What is the lifespan of modules and providers in a NestJS application? Do they last for the lifespan of a request, or the application, or something else?
3. Are there any lifecycle hooks, in addition to `OnModuleInit` and `OnModuleDestroy`?
4. What causes a Module to be destroyed (and trigger the `OnModuleDestroy` event)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What is the order of execution of the following processes in a request, for a route that implements: middleware, pipes, guards, interceptors, and any other potential request process

The common order is:

- Middlewares
- Guards
- Interceptors (before the stream is manipulated)
- Pipes
- Interceptors (after the stream is manipulated)
- Exception filters (if any exception is caught)

> What is the lifespan of modules and providers in a NestJS application? Do they last for the lifespan of a request, or the application, or something else?

They do last for the lifespan of the application. Modules are destroyed when a NestApplication or a NestMicroservice is being closed (see `close` method from `INestApplication`).

> Are there any lifecycle hooks, in addition to OnModuleInit and OnModuleDestroy?

No there aren't at the moment.

> What causes a Modeule to be destroyed (and trigger the OnModuleDestroy event)?

See my answer to the second point. As you look interested in lifecyle hooks, you might pay some interest to issues [#938](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/938) and [#550](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/550)

Comment: what is the best place to remove password data?

Comment: If you are talking about **input** data, you don't need to remove anything, but to be careful about how you store the data, and where you store it (I'd highly recommend to only store hashes using, for instance, `bcrypt` algorithm). If you are talking about **output** data, then Nest already proposes a way to do that, using Serialization. Please refer to the documentation: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/serialization. If you want to do it yourself, I'd recommend using reflection and decorators, combined with interceptors (but this is done by Serialization).

Comment: yep. output data. I figured out that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> What is the order of execution of the following processes in a request, for a route that implements: middleware, pipes, guards, interceptors, and any other potential request process

Middleware -> Guards -> Interceptors (code before `next.handle()`) -> Pipes -> Route Handler -> Interceptors (eg: `next.handle().pipe( tap(() => changeResponse()) )` )-> Exception Filter (if exception is thrown)

With all three of them, you can inject other dependencies (like services,...) in their constructor.

> What is the lifespan of modules and providers in a NestJS application? Do they last for the lifespan of a request, or the application, or something else?

A provider can have any of the following scopes:

`SINGLETON` - A single instance of the provider is shared across the entire application. The instance lifetime is tied directly to the application lifecycle. Once the application has bootstrapped, all singleton providers have been instantiated. Singleton scope is used by default.

`REQUEST` - A new instance of the provider is created exclusively for each incoming request. The instance is garbage-collected after the request has completed processing.

`TRANSIENT` - Transient providers are not shared across consumers. Each consumer that injects a transient provider will receive a new, dedicated instance.

Using singleton scope is recommended for most use cases. Sharing providers across consumers and across requests means that an instance can be cached and its initialization occurs only once, during application startup.

Example

```
import { Injectable, Scope } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class CatsService {}
```

> Are there any lifecycle hooks, in addition to OnModuleInit and OnModuleDestroy?

`OnApplicationBootstrap` - Called once the application has fully started and is bootstrapped
`OnApplicationShutdown` - Responds to the system signals (when application gets shutdown by e.g. SIGTERM). Use this hook to gracefully shutdown a Nest application. This feature is often used with Kubernetes, Heroku or similar services.

Both `OnModuleInit` and `OnApplicationBootstrap` hooks allow you to defer the application initialization process (return a Promise or mark the method as async).

> What causes a Module to be destroyed (and trigger the OnModuleDestroy event)?

Usually shutdown signal from Kubernetes, Heroku or similar services.